# Coloring labels in color of features automatically in ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, labeling

I have map project in ArcMap. My labels on the map are one color. I want to color the labels in color as polygons, where the labels are places.

[image]

Comment: Won't that make them invisible? Labels are usually another colour to make them distinct, if you really want to do that then explore the help file and search for label classes.

Comment: You should switch to qgis :-)

Comment: No-brainer with QGIS!

Comment: @Hornbydd you have a good point, although I note that the OP is using a label mask.  So if the user chose a mask color that was different than the poly fill colors, it seems to me that the label text would then be insulated from the fill color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a way to do this, but it is slightly clunky in your case, but nonetheless will work fine after implementing: use ArcGIS "text formatting tags".

Text formatting tags allow you to give a specific portion of a label dedicated text formatting, e.g. a different font or as in your case font color for part of the label if the label is based on more than one field. E.g. you could set the label text for FIELD 1 to bold and red, and for FIELD 2 to italic and blue using text formatting tags, all in one label that concatenates the two fields values in the label expression.

However, if you embed the text formatting tags in the actual label field, the ArcGIS labelling engine will produce dedicated formatting ***for each record***, so a different color for each label as in your polygons.

However, as you understand, this requires adding a new **text** type field, and calculating its contents based on the original label field using the Field Calculator, including the text formatting tags in the calculation expression. E.g. put something like this in the Field Calculator to calculate the field:

```
<CLR red = "255" green = "100" blue = "50"> [YOUR_LABEL_FIELD] </CLR>
```

One big caveat though is also, that you will need to determine the RGB colors beforehand, and embed them in the calculation manually, you cannot directly derive the polygon symbology's color values and use them in an automated way, so this is likely only a viable option with a very limited set of colors for your polygons.

And of course, you will also need to select the specific record(s) for which you want that color to apply before calculating those record(s).

**General information about all available text formatting tags:**
https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/map/working-with-text/formatting-tags-available-in-arcmap.htm

**Some specifics about embedding text formatting in fields:**
https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/map/working-with-text/using-text-formatting-tags-about-text-formatting-t.htm#GUID-DCF8F600-277A-4DE3-8CDF-B1B3047CCB55

Note that if you are using **ArcGIS Pro**, there is a new option called [**"Attribute-driven symbology"**](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/mapping/layer-properties/attribute-driven-symbology.htm#ESRI_SECTION1_5E319812B4E14CEBAE02E002305EB0EA) (likely resembles QGIS options), that makes implementing something like probably this easier. I must admit I haven't yet tried this out though, and I don't know right now if it is applicable to labels as well. You could though use it to enter the RGB values in a field, and subsequently use the field to drive the polygon symbology colors and add a secondary field including the text formatting based on a calculation referencing the same field.

Comment: Thank you for advice, but still I don't understand how to learn color of polygon

Comment: Double click the symbol in the ArcGIS TOC (Table of Contents, where the layers are visible on the left). Then click the color "drop down", and from there choose "More colors" at the bottom, this opens the "Color Selector". You should now see the RGB values listed for the specific color your symbol has. If the dialog is not displaying RGB but HSV or CMYK instead, use the color mode drop down selector in the top right to switch to RGB. These are the RGB values you should enter in the text formatting tags.

Comment: I want to do this automatically using python

Comment: Unfortunately, unless you upgrade to ArcGIS Pro, you cannot automate getting the RGB values from the symbology using Python and ArcPy. ArcPy in ArcMap does not give access to the color info in symbology. In ArcGIS Pro, you could access it using the new (from Pro 2.4 onwards) Python CIM access (CIM=Cartographic Information Model that determines all properties of layers in ArcGIS). See https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/mapping/python-cim-access.htm

Comment: Thank you for advice